# User info not loading into firebase auth

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a very simple login with Facebook using firebase and android studio. My login with Facebook works and I was able to run the app and sign in but none of my info has been stored in firebase (I want to have the persons name, email, etc.) I know it's something small I am probably missing but I cannot figure it out and I have tried so many things. Also I checked and all my gradle files are up to date and my firebase is set up correctly so it has nothing to do with that. plz help.

```
firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


            if(user != null){

      // what do i put here to pull out the fb users info into firebase?!

                goMainScreen();
            }
        }
    };
```

I have tried:

```
if(user != null){
String name = user.getDisplayName();
String email = user.getEmail();
String uid = user.getUid();
```

I have tried:

```
if (user != null) {
            // User is signed in
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
        } else {
            // User is signed out
            Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
        }
```

I know it is probably a dumb mistake because I am new to firebase and android studio but any advice will help. Thank you

Comment: `I have tried so many things` - like what? Did you run into any specific exceptions that you could share with us to help troubleshoot?

Comment: Have you set a break point on the `if (user != null)` to see what is happening during execution? This would show if the user variable is holding the user info. Also, you will see if that code is reached.

Answer (score -1):

Are your user stored into the firebase console? (https://console.firebase.google.com)

If it is not stored in your project, it will not return anything when you call the getDisplayName(), getUser(), etc.

If they are stored, please post the complete code that you are using to do the login.