# firebase user registration with google/facebook account in android

Tags: android, firebase, authentication

i developed an application which has the google sign-in functionalityby using the codes in the link https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java#L89-L89 and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin . Users can sign-in with their google account. It's OK until here. However, users are not registered to firebase. I cannot see the users which has signed in with google.

A similar question has been asked in stackoverflow :

[User info not loading into firebase auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42938163/user-info-not-loading-into-firebase-auth)

however it has not replied my question.

On the web, there is tutorials about signing in with google, facebook, etc. However, registration has not been mentioned.

When users signed in with google/facebook account, what should i do? Do they registered automatically to firebase users, or should i add them to database manually? How should i behave about this?

What does common applications do after a user sign in with google/facebook account? Do they  register users manually when a user signed in with google/facebook, or any other thing?

Comment: Have you consider using Firebase-Ui https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android ?

Comment: @cutiko I havent heard about firebase-ui before. Why do i need it in my situation?

Comment: you don't need it, you can do it all by your self, but you can benefit by it by speeding up the implementation